# Is there a way to unstake a liquidity token when the frontend of the platform is down part2

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

hey there can someone plz help me out with this. im having issues unlock my LP from uniswap using etherscan im actually on the last step im looking for ( Go to the field 5. exitswapPoolAmountIn)
but i cant seem to find it on etherscan [!https://etherscan.io/address/0x8fd3a04cb30a1fd9ffaf1548972b2e5117d0a52d#writeContract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lRPG.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lRPG.png)

Comment: Please provide more context about the specific liquidity pool and tokens involved, as well as any error messages or issues encountered during the unstaking process. 

When asking a question on Stack Overflow, ensure to include all relevant details such as the specific platform or protocol being used, any error messages received, and steps already attempted. Providing clear and concise information will help others understand and assist with the problem effectively.

Comment: Surething will this is the contract :0x8Fd3A04CB30A1fD9fFaF1548972B2e5117D0a52D that im trying to unlock my LP from its been there for more then 2 years frontend of uniswapV2 is not working i spoke with the team they sent me dose guide to remove it i have done everything im on the last step but i cant seem to find (9. Go to the field 5. exitswapPoolAmountIn i think ETHERSCAN switch there formart on write contracts :https://docs.oceanprotocol.com/user-guides/remove-liquidity-pools